# Pthreads: Thread calls to functions with multiple parameters

Tags: parameters, pthreads, parameter-passing

I have two functions I want to call using threads created from the pthread API:

```
int request_resources(int customer_num, int request[]);
int release_resources(int customer_num, int release[]);
```

I'm confused as to how to accomplish this.  I thought you could only pass one parameter into the function by way of:

```
pthread_create(thread,attr,start_routine,arg)
```

I have been asked to create a number of threads and then have them pass random values into the request and release functions, but how do I pass both the customer_num and the request[] vector?  I thought of using a struct, but the function I'm provided with has the two parameters shown above.  Is it possible to pass multiple arguments to a function with multiple parameters using pthreads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a pointer to a struct is the way to solve this. If you cannot modify your current functions to receive a single parameter which will be this pointer, you'll need to create a shim function that does the conversion. Consider:

```
void shim(struct x *arg)
{
    request_resources(arg->customer_num, arg->request);
}
```

and specify `shim` as the thread's entry point.